# Read Excel File As it Shown When Open in excel Application using c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

When i open excel in Application(Microsoft) date appears like "22-oct-2020" but when I read it through interop It is like "2020-10-22". I want it to be read it as it show in excel in Application(Microsoft).

[Here is the output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yQfO.png)

[Here is the date in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lfCV.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yy")
```

You can get more info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: I want interop to skip parse date. I want interop to give me that "22-oct-2020" string instead of converting it into date.

Comment: @waqas I do not believe that is possible. The date is stored in only one format but displayed in many formats. You can tell it to display the date in the sheet in many formats but it is still stored in only one format. There is a separation between the data and how it is displayed to the user. You will also have many formats to display it to your users in your app.

Comment: Thanks bro,
I am just stuck in validating date from excel.